# How much damage does `bleeding` do over time?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Both the in-game information for Divinity: Original Sin Enhanced Edition and that provided by [the wiki page](https://divinityoriginalsin.wiki.fextralife.com/Status+Effects#buffs) mention that bleeding deals damage over time but don't give you any idea of how much damage. They might as well not tell you anything at all! How much damage does this effect deal?

Answer (score 2):

From the image below, you can see in this specific case it does: 196-338 slashing damage (per turn).
The Special tells you how long the bleeding is for (3 turns in this case)

So with a 120% chance, Lacerate will deal between 196-1014 damage total over 3 turns.
Or (I think) at minimum 196 damage.

How much damage is always based on the skill used to cause the damage.

[image]

Comment: Really? Wow, that's really powerful. I thought that damage was the damage of the attack and then there was some amount of bleeding damage on top of it. So Lacerate deals 150% of your attack damage reach turn for 3 turns?

Comment: Not sure where you got 150% should be between 196-338 per turn

Comment: 150% is from the wiki information: https://divinityoriginalsin.wiki.fextralife.com/Lacerate